# Jquery trying to increment the data delay for every child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to increment the delay of every data-attribute inside the div element.

See my code
JQUERY

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var Column = [], startDelayTime, counter;
    Column = $('.col-outside');
    startDelayTime = 300;
    addDelayTime = 25;

    for(var i = 0; i < Column.length; i++) {
        Column.attr('data-sal-delay', startDelayTime + addDelayTime[i]);
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-outside" data-sal="slide-right" data-sal-easing="ease-out-bounce" data-sal-delay="300">
```

Hopefully someone can explain me what i am doing wrong, or what i have to do.

Comment: What's the problem with your current code?

Comment: it's staying on 300 for every data attribute and i want the first one on 300 the second one on 325... keep going

Comment: @OtoTheZ Startdelaytime[i] possibly.

Comment: i have tried that but nothing happend so i am very confused. I am a beginner in coding so maybe someone can help me on stackoverflow.

Comment: @OtoTheZ Initialise the adddelaytime variable with var in front of the variable like this var addDelayTime = 25;

Comment: I Have done that

Comment: @OtoTheZ Did the above help? Feedback would be good.

Answer (score 0):

The logic in your loop needs to look like this. I removed the JQuery logic to simplify the example.

```
var currentDelay = 300;
var addDelayTime = 25;

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // Column.attr('data-sal-delay', currentDelay);
    console.log(currentDelay);
    currentDelay += addDelayTime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code.

1. Within your loop, you need to access the single column node using `Column[i]` in order to set an attribute.
2. [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) is a jQuery method, so you need to use it on a jQuery selection like `$(Column[i]).attr(name, value)`. Or you could just use the javascript method [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) like `Column[i].setAttribute(name, value)`
3. `addDelayTime` is an integer so `addDelayTime[i]` is undefined. What you want to do here instead is multiply `addDelayTime` by the current array index.  `addDelayTime * i`

In this example I've fixed the above 3 issues and instead of a for loop I've used jQuery's [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate over the columns.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var startDelayTime = 300;
  var addDelayTime = 25;

  $.each($(".col-outside"), function(index, item) {
    $(item).attr("data-sal-delay", startDelayTime + index * addDelayTime);
  });
});
```

```css
.col-outside::after {
  content: attr(data-sal-delay);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-outside"></div>
<div class="col-outside"></div>
<div class="col-outside"></div>
<div class="col-outside"></div>
<div class="col-outside"></div>
```

Comment: If that solves your problem, be sure to click on the ✓ to accept the answer.

Comment: What works?  While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers

Answer (score 0):

This will work:
You need to multiply by i on delayStart to get desired effect.

```
$(function() {
    var Column = [], startDelayTime, counter;
    Column = $('.col-outside');
    startDelayTime = 300;
    addDelayTime = 25;

    Column.each(function(i, c){
        $(c).attr('data-sal-delay', startDelayTime+ (addDelayTime*i));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things:

1. Use the current column in your loop (`Column[i]` rather than `Column`).
2. Increment the value of `startDelayTime` every time the loop iterates.

Here's your edited code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var Column = [], startDelayTime, counter;
    Column = $('.col-outside');
    startDelayTime = 300;
    addDelayTime = 25;

    for(var i = 0; i < Column.length; i++) {
        Column[i].attr('data-sal-delay', startDelayTime + addDelayTime);
        startDelayTime += addDelayTime;
    }
});
```

Now your code should work. Hopefully this helps!